# How can I call a method when data binding gridview to edit data before displaying it?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, data-binding, edit

```
<asp:Label ID="RespiteDay" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("StepRespiteDay")%>' </asp:Label>
```

i want to call below method and edit "StepRespiteDay"

```
PersianDateTime persianDate1 = new PersianDateTime("StepRespiteDay");
persianDate1.ToString("dddd dd MMMM yyyy");
```

then i want to display persianDate1 instead of "StepRespiteDay"
what should i do?

thank you very much.

Comment: _What_ method below? I just see an object initialization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a method in your code-behind that returns a `string`, like this:

```
protected string DisplayRespiteDate(object stepRespiteDay)
{
    DateTime theDate;

    // Attempt to cast object to DateTime
    try
    {
        theDate = (DateTime)stepRespiteDay;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        // Do something with failed conversion here, throw for example
        throw;
    }

    return theDate.ToString("dddd dd MMMM yyyy");
}
```

Now in your markup you can call the method, like this:

```
<asp:Label ID="RespiteDay" runat="server" 
           Text='<%# DisplayRespiteDate(Eval("StepRespiteDay"))%>'   
</asp:Label>
```

Comment: this is exactly what I need :) thank you very much Mr Anderson :)